# How to get last week activities in GetStream

Tags: getstream-io

I would like to send an e-mail summary to all users every week or so with the latest activities. To do this, I would like to get the activities between two dates.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no datetime filter, sorted recent as last by default. Simple read the feed while paginating and keep the part relevant to you.

Otherwise, you can push activities to week/monthly feeds with to targeting and then simply read these feeds for the respective week/month.